# Make Python code with third party libraries useable for unix server

Tags: python, unix, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a Python script which uses NumPy and another third party library. The third party library is written in Python and has no bindings to other languages. It makes us of Cython, SciPy, NumPy and Matplotlib. Though I only use a small subset of this library, it has no easy replacement (scientific software).

I'd like to use a computing server to run my program, since it takes over 10 hours to finish. Needless to say there is no support for python. So I see two possibilities: precompile my code for Unix or convert it to C/C++.

**What I tried:**

- shedskin: Doesn't work with unsupported libraries
- cx_freeze et al.: Countless errors, it's difficult to make simple programs work
- PyInstaller: Doesn't work using OpenSuse. Is not able to resolve the dependencies of third party libraries
- Nuitka: I get a memory error

Any suggestions on what to do are welcome.

Comment: If its a standard unix box, cant you use pip?

Comment: Take a look at Nuitka, but I'm not sure if it supports those libraries.  http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html

Comment: @muddyfish Could you provide some extra information please? I'm not proficient with Unix.

Comment: in the command line, type in 'pip install numpy','pip install scipy','pip install matplotlib' etc. If they dont work, try using the 'pip search' command to see if you can find the packages yourself

Comment: @muddyfish I don't have the rights to use pip. Sorry for my misunderstanding. Next I'll try to build Python from source, I suspect it might work.

Comment: You can use virtualenv to get round that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda/Miniconda is a perfect fit for this problem. It installs locally to your users home directory and installs all the binaries you need (with minimal effort to add extra custom packages). It's designed specifically with the python science ecosystem (and all it's annoying build dependencies) in mind.

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
export PATH=$PATH:~/miniconda/bin
conda install numpy scipy matplotlib cython
```

You also get the nice side effect that installing a new machine will take seconds to minutes rather than minutes to hours.

Once it's setup, it's also compatible with pip (ie/ it puts a local copy of pip beside conda)

Comment: Great answer! If I may add: I had to change the mode with `chmod +x <file>.sh`